# How to redirect to a different page clicking on an Image in silverlight 3.0?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a slide show of some images in my silverlight application.

When user clicks on any Image I want want to redirect to a different page.

How to implement this.

Please help.

Comment: Note this isn't redirection this is navigation, redirection happens when you try to navigate then the server redirects the request to another URL.

Answer (score 2):

From Silverlight you can catch/handle the MouseLeftButtonUp event and do

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Check this url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage_members%28VS.95%29.aspx
I can't find Navigate as member of HtmlPage class. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

HTML.Navigate won't open a new page in several browsers.  This makes it kind of worthless.

However, `HyperlinkButtons` magically make it work.  I don't know how, so I just create a one of those, give it the URI that I want to open, and click it (all from code).  if I set the `TargetName` of the `HyperlinkButton` to "_Blank" then it will open in a new page.

Calling a buttons click event from code isn't the easiest either, but I found some code somewhere that did it.  Here's the code that you will need to open a new page:

```
    HyperlinkButton button = new HyperlinkButton();            
    button.NavigateUri = new URI("The URI To Go To");
    button.TargetName = "_Blank";

    HyperlinkButtonAutomationPeer hyperlinkPeer = new HyperlinkButtonAutomationPeer(button);
    IInvokeProvider invokeProvider = hyperlinkPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    invokeProvider.Invoke();
```

Comment: I wish there was an easier way to do this.  I guess it just goes to show, the microsoft people don't test on macs.